# Reading packet header with jpcap

Tags: java, packet-sniffers, jpcap

I'm trying to read packet headers using jpcap.

```
TCPPacket tcpPacket = (TCPPacket) captor.getPacket();
System.out.println(new String(tcpPacket.header));
```

and the output is (something like):
[image]

What am I missing? (When reading the data part, it looks OK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TCPPacket.getHeader()` returns a `byte[]` array, which you can't expect to contain only nice ASCII values, so when you make a (UTF-8) `String` out of it, you get line noise...

AFAIK there is no structured approach to TCP headers in JPCap, so you'll have to [dig out a reference](http://nmap.org/book/tcpip-ref.html) and decode it yourself - or use Google to [find resources](https://java.net/projects/slamd/sources/svn/content/trunk/slamd/tools/LDAPDecoder/src/com/sun/snoop/TCPHeader.java) by people who've done the work already.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! The link you provided did the trick (https://java.net/projects/slamd/sources/svn/content/trunk/slamd/tools/LDAPDecoder/src/com/sun/snoop/TCPHeader.java?rev=226)